# Dealing with Oracle ARCHIVELOG during huge updates

Tags: oracle, sql-update, oracle11gr2

It's required to update columns with metadata globally in all rows of all tables in DB. Let's say every table has a column `MY_META` and the aim is roughly

```
update ANOTHER_TABLE set MY_META = 'HELLO'
```

for each table.

Estimated total rows count is `2e9`.

Suppose ARCHIVELOG mode is on, so during those updates a lot of extra space is going to be consumed.

The process of updates is planned to be running in production DB simultaneously with business transactions, which should not be lost.

The simplest thing to start with is temporarily installing plenty of hardware for ARCHIVELOG files.

Is there an elegant way to achieve the same goal programmatically or via tuning "secret options"?

Comment: One simple optimization is to add `WHERE nvl(my_meta,'XXX') != 'HELLO'`.  You would think that Oracle would not generate archive log info when no data is changed, but it does.  (Or, did, last time I bothered to test it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your clarifications, I understand that:

- for each table, you have a value of `MY_META` that you want to assign to each row as an *initial* value.
- you don't mind dropping `MY_META` and recreating it.

In this case, I would suggest that you drop `MY_META` and recreate it with a default value.  If you do this, Oracle will not update every record with your initial value and the amount of redo generated will be minimal.

The downside is that the `ALTER TABLE` commands, though very fast, will briefly lock each table as you process it.  It will also invalidate packages that depend on the `MY_META` column.

Here is a walkthrough of the approach, with comments:

```
-- Set up your current state
DROP TABLE my_big_table;
CREATE TABLE my_big_table (a number, my_meta varchar2(30) not null);
INSERT INTO my_big_table (a, my_meta) SELECT rownum, 'GARBAGE' FROM dual CONNECT BY rownum <= 100000;

-- Drop the my_meta column and replace it with one having a default value
ALTER TABLE my_big_table DROP COLUMN my_meta;
ALTER TABLE my_big_table ADD my_meta  varchar2(30) default 'INITIAL_VAL_FOR_TABLE' not null;

-- Look at my table -- you will see every row has your initial value
SELECT * FROM my_big_table;

-- Update some data
update my_big_table set my_meta = 'UPDATED_VALUE' WHERE a <= 15;

-- Look at my table -- you will see every row has your initial value except the first 15.
SELECT * FROM my_big_table order by a;
```